# Rule to move all mails from the users of a Distribution List to a Folder

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, rules

We are using Outlook 2007, and I wanted to create a rule that would move all the emails coming from any of the users that are a part of a specific Distribution List to a specific folder.

I have tried creating a new rule using the option which says "from people or distribution list" but its not working.

Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: What type of DL do you mean? Local group of contacts or Exchange Server's?

Comment: Its the one on the Exchange Server.

Comment: would need a screenshot of the rule to see why it's not working.