# Outlook move emails from member of nested distribution list

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2013

At my company we have a nested distribution list like this:

DL all, which contains DL1, DL2, DL3 and every containts further lists DL1a, DL1b, DL2a and so on. These lists are on our exchange server and it is outlook 2013.
This question is the same as mine but was not answered yet: [Rule to move all mails from the users of a Distribution List to a Folder](https://superuser.com/questions/380106/rule-to-move-all-mails-from-the-users-of-a-distribution-list-to-a-folder)

I had a rule which was triggered by: Apply this rule after the messages arrives from DL all, move it to folder x.

This worked for 2 years but since monday it stopped working. really weird!

I tried to use change this rule to: Apply this rule after the messages arrives SENT to DL all, ... but that also does not work.

I want outlook to go through this distribution lists and if this email was sent by anyone being part of that DL all to move it. Adding a single person with his email address works as expected.

Comment: Exchange has been acting screwy since Friday. I think they're applying some changes. I would say give it a couple of days to see if it corrects itself.

Comment: @BenPlont thank you very much. I hope this is true.. really missing all the auto cleaning and ordering of emails

Comment: The issue is that it is not always a 1 to 1 relationship between person and list. How do expect Outlook to know that a specific person belongs to a specific distribution list(s)? You can apply a rule to a distribution list name, but I think you're expecting much if you want Outlook smart about moving based on group membership.

Comment: @sunk818 you can look it up which dl a user belongs to. in addition it worked for 2 years and I did not change the rule

Comment: If the user belongs to more than one dl, then which folder do they get moved to? Can show us a screenshot of your current rule that is broken?

Comment: it does not matter which dl he belongs to. I just want everyone who is part of this dl to be moved to a specific folder. e.g. Lets assume dl Engineers. Now I would like to have everyone who is part of this engineer dl to be moved to a folder called engineers. does not matter who he is or if the has multiple roles.